# Javascript Date() constructor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, date

The javascript `Date("mm-dd-yyyy")` constructor doesn't work for FF.  It works fine for IE.

- IE : `new Date("04-02-2008")` => `"Wed Apr 2 00:00:00 EDT 2008"`
- FF2 : `new Date("04-02-2008")` => `Invalid Date`

So let's try another constructor: `Date("yyyy", "mm", "dd")`.

- IE: `new Date("2008", "04", "02");` => `"Fri May 2 00:00:00 EDT 2008"`
- FF: `new Date("2008", "04", "02");` => `"Fri May 2 00:00:00 EDT 2008"`
- IE: `new Date("2008", "03", "02");` => `"Wed Apr 2 00:00:00 EDT 2008"`
- FF: `new Date("2008", "03", "02");` => `"Wed Apr 2 00:00:00 EDT 2008"`

So the `Date("yyyy", "mm", "dd")` constructor uses an index of `0` to represent January.

How do I best deal with this other than subtracting 1 from the months?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is the [definition of the Date object](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to use values 0-11 for the `month` field.

I believe that the constructor using a String is system-dependent (not to mention locale/timezone dependent) so you are probably better off using the constructor where you specify year/month/day as separate parameters.

BTW, in Firefox,

```
new Date("04/02/2008");
```

It works fine for me - it will interpret slashes, but not hyphens. This proves my point that using a String to construct a Date object is problematic. Use explicit values for month/day/year instead:

```
new Date(2008, 3, 2);
```

Answer (score 17):

nice trick indeed, which I just found out the hard way (by thinking through it).
But I used a more natural date string with a hyphen :-)

```
var myDateArray = "2008-03-02".split("-");
var theDate = new Date(myDateArray[0],myDateArray[1]-1,myDateArray[2]); 
alert(theDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
var theDate = new Date(myDate[0],myDate[1]-1,myDate[2]);
```

Is fine, but it shows some strange behaviors when month and day values are erroneous.

Try casting a date where both `myDate[1]-1` and `myDate[2]` have values of 55. Javascript still returns a date, though the input is obviously not correct.

I would have preferred javascript to return an error in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

@Frank: you are right. When you need to validate date,

```
var theDate = new Date(myDate[0],myDate[1]-1,myDate[2]);
```

will not work.

What happens is that it keeps on adding the extra parameter. For example:

```
new Date("2012", "11", "57") // Date {Sat Jan 26 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

Date object takes the extra days (57-31=26) and adds it to the date we created.

Or if we try constructing a date object with:

```
new Date("2012", "11", "57", "57") //Date {Mon Jan 28 2013 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

an extra 2 days and 9 hours (57=24+24+9) are added.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, month is indicated as an index, so January is month number 0 and December is month number 11 ...

-- and there is no work-around as it is stated clearly in the ECMA-script-definition, though simple tricks commonly will work:

```
var myDate = "2008,03,02".split(",");
var theDate = new Date(myDate[0],myDate[1]-1,myDate[2]); 
alert(theDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bold statement.

This might have your interest: [JavaScript Pretty Date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/).