# Javascript Timestamp from ISO8061

Tags: javascript, timestamp, iso8601

I'm having a bit of an issue when dealing with getting a timestamp from an iso8061 date. 
For some reason it work perfectly in Chrome, but causes an Invalid Date error in Firefox. The exact line is:

```
var date = new Date(time.replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," "));
```

I've tried passing the date through (as the var time) `2011-03-09T16:46:58+00:00`, `2011-03-09T16:46:58+0000` and `2011-03-09T16:48:37Z` as per the spec outlined http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#dates but I still can't seem to get it to work in firefox. In fact, the last method didn't work in either browser.

If anyone could help me turn this iso8061 date into a timestamp, that would be great.

Thanks,
Angelo R.

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp", exactly?

Comment: @lwburk a unix style timestamp, essentially the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at [JavaScript ISO8601/RFC3339 Date Parser](http://dansnetwork.com/javascript-iso8601rfc3339-date-parser/):

their code:

```
Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function(dString){
    var regexp = /(\d\d\d\d)(-)?(\d\d)(-)?(\d\d)(T)?(\d\d)(:)?(\d\d)(:)?(\d\d)(\.\d+)?(Z|([+-])(\d\d)(:)?(\d\d))/;
    if (dString.toString().match(new RegExp(regexp))) {
        var d = dString.match(new RegExp(regexp));
        var offset = 0;
        this.setUTCDate(1);
        this.setUTCFullYear(parseInt(d[1],10));
        this.setUTCMonth(parseInt(d[3],10) - 1);
        this.setUTCDate(parseInt(d[5],10));
        this.setUTCHours(parseInt(d[7],10));
        this.setUTCMinutes(parseInt(d[9],10));
        this.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(d[11],10));
        if (d[12]) {
            this.setUTCMilliseconds(parseFloat(d[12]) * 1000);
        }
        else {
            this.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
        }
        if (d[13] != 'Z') {
            offset = (d[15] * 60) + parseInt(d[17],10);
            offset *= ((d[14] == '-') ? -1 : 1);
            this.setTime(this.getTime() - offset * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        this.setTime(Date.parse(dString));
    }
    return this;
};
```

and then you can use it this way:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setISO8601('2008-12-19T16:39:57.67Z');
```

probably not that comfortable, but you can rewrite this function, or write another one which will return date based on ISO-8601 format

Comment: Why not just use `new Date(someTimeString)`?

Comment: The reason to use it is because, unfortunately, not all browsers' JavaScript engines support the ISO-8601 format (ISO-8601 = http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

The way that the `Date` constructor handles string arguments differs across browsers. As the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work) points out, IE recognizes hyphens, but Firefox does not, as just one example.

It's probably best to use the constructor that expects individual date parts.