# JavaScript Date getTime() inconsistent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a parser for the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com) for jQuery and I have this strange behaviour with the getTime() value for dates. The following code:

```
var dateOne = '03/04/2010';
var dateTwo = '28/10/2008';
var dateOneTime = new Date(dateOne).getTime();
var dateTwoTime = new Date(dateTwo).getTime();
var diff = dateOneTime - dateTwoTime;

alert('dateOneTime: ' + dateOneTime + '\ndateOne: ' + dateOne + '\nDateTwoTime: ' + dateTwoTime + '\ndateTwo : ' + dateTwo + '\none - two: ' + diff);
```

Gives a getTime() result for the 2010 date as 1267 billion or so, and for the 2008 date 1271 billion. Therefore subtracting dateTwo from dateOne gives a negative number. Why is this? Surely the dateTwo value, being in 2008, should be smaller?

Comment: Avoid using the string constructor altogether if possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date expects `MM/DD/YYYY`

You are passing in `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: Yes. This is it. I am an idiot. (I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept your answer).

Answer (score 1):

By default, the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.  Thus, `28/10/2008` is being interpreted as `04/10/2010`.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a date in JS [via a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it should be an RFC1123-compliant format - yours aren't.

Answer (score 0):

new Date(dateTwo) is being interpreted incorrectly as April 10 2010 because the Date constructor is expecting MM/DD/YYYY instead of the DD/MM/YYYY you are passing.

try

```
var dateOne = '04/03/2010';
var dateTwo = '10/28/2008';
```