# new Data in javascript returns different date

Tags: javascript, date

Input: `new Date("2013-03-28")`

Output: `Wed Mar 27 2013 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

How do I get 28 instead of 27. Is this a javascript default issue?

Comment: 2013-03-28 00:00 UTC happens to be 2013-03-27 17:00 GMT -0700.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612631/javascript-date-why-is-the-date-new-date2011-12-13-considered-a-monday-and-n/8612658#8612658

Comment: You might want to consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [ISO-formatted dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), either all or in-part, the timezone may be assumed to be UTC.

```
console.log(new Date("2013-03-28").toUTCString());
// "Thu, 28 Mar 2013 00:00:00 GMT"
```

To create the date in local time, you can use a different overload of the constructor (note that `month` is 0-indexed, so `2` is March):

```
console.log(new Date(2013, 2, 28).toString());
// "Thu Mar 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (...)"
```