# jquery date conversion chrome works but IE and firefox don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

Lost here.  The following works in Chrome wonderfully, but in IE and FireFox 
"undefined undefined NaN Nan" is returned

What am I missing?

```
var dateString = $(this).attr("ows_EventDate");
var current_date = new Date(dateString);
var month_names = [];
month_names[month_names.length] = "January";
month_names[month_names.length] = "February";
month_names[month_names.length] = "March";
month_names[month_names.length] = "April";
month_names[month_names.length] = "May";
month_names[month_names.length] = "June";
month_names[month_names.length] = "July";
month_names[month_names.length] = "August";
month_names[month_names.length] = "September";
month_names[month_names.length] = "October";
month_names[month_names.length] = "November";
month_names[month_names.length] = "December";
var day_names = [];
day_names[day_names.length] = "Sunday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Monday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Tuesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Wednesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Thursday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Friday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Saturday";

var startU = (day_names[current_date.getDay()]) + (", ") 
  + (month_names[current_date.getMonth()]) + (" ") + current_date.getDate() 
  + (" ") + (" ") + current_date.getFullYear();
```

Chrome returns... Thursday, February 23 2012   etc, etc just perfectly.

Comment: what is the value for the value coming out of `$(this).attr("ows_EventDate")`?

Comment: This jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rgMmH/ works fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE9.  Since you haven't included the value of `$(this).attr("ows_EventDate");`, I had to bypass that.

Comment: Also, do you realize that this is a very inefficient way to declare your arrays.  You can just do this; `var day_names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];`

Comment: I realize that it's horribly inefficient now.  Newb = me :)  The value that coming in, for the February example above, would be "2012-02-04 21:00:00"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dateString must be formatted correctly. ISO 8601 date formats should work (http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format)

In your comment you said `dateString` is equal to `2012-02-04 21:00:00`. Replacing the space with a `T` would make it a valid date format that all browsers can parse, for example:

`2012-02-04T21:00:00`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TQjhP/

Comment: Got it, appreciate the jsfiddle too

Answer (score 1):

Your date `"2012-02-04 21:00:00"` is not accepted by the `Date()` constructor in IE.

See this related post for details: [Javascript Date() constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work).

The spec for what the `Date()` constructor is supposed to accept as a string is [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) if you really want the details of what is legal.

Apparently, Firefox and IE work with `"2012/02/04 21:00:00"`.

See [this article](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari) for further discussion.