# new Date is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

Can you tell me why this is not working on Firefox (V 34 latest) ? It's working fine on all other browsers. 'DatePosted' is shown as Invalid Date.Why ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 //Get local time for everything:
       data.Comments.forEach(function (x) {
         x.DatePosted = new Date(x.DatePosted.toString().replace("T", " ") + " UTC");
      });
```

[image]

**Note :** x.DatePosted :  "2014-11-18T08:06:39.06"

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery date conversion chrome works but IE and firefox don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595902/jquery-date-conversion-chrome-works-but-ie-and-firefox-dont) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok

Comment: Can you please post the value of `x.DatePosted.toString()` ?

Comment: @RahulDesai It's like this : "2014-11-18T08:06:39.06"

Comment: why do you need the .replace("T"," ") inside the constructor call of Date? It should work with-out it.

Comment: @Sampath Please checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to replace the `T`. It works without it (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

After setting the Date object, get it into UTC.

Working snippet below:

```js
var myDate = new Date("2014-11-18T08:06:39.06");

// now set it to UTC
var myDateinUTC = Date.UTC(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDate(), myDate.getHours(), myDate.getMinutes(), myDate.getSeconds(), myDate.getMilliseconds());

console.dir(myDateinUTC);

var myNewDate = new Date(myDateinUTC);

console.log(myNewDate.getMonth()); // just to test
```

Comment: Yes.I have used without replace part and now it's working.Thanks a lot :)