# Problems with outputting date using WebApi/MVC4/Knockout

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js

I am getting dates back in the format: 2012-07-22T:14:45:00

I need to know how to format in JS in order to display in a specific format i.e. 22/07/2012

If I do this:

```
var date = new Date(self.StartTime());
alert("test " + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear());
```

I actually get 22/06/2012 which is a month out??

Answer (score 2):

[`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns the zero-based month number:

> The value returned by `getMonth` is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

So you need to add one to get the one-based month number you want and then you account for one digit months by manually adding the missing zero. You'll also want to account for single digit `getDate` values as well.

Comment: Is there no simpler way to format into a readable date/time from the format 2012-07-22T:14:45:00?

Comment: @user1166905 If this is not simple for you then you can also use a date library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: It's just not clean enough for me to have to add 1 to the month and also hours are coming out an hour out as well.

Comment: @user1166905: An hour? Do you have a timezone problem?

Comment: Looking at the JSON it appears it's being returned an hour out by WebApi. not to do with format date afterwards.

Comment: @user1166905: The server is probably return a UTC timestamp, have you look at what [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) says?

Comment: It is -60, what can I do with this to get correct info, somehow change the minutes+getTimezoneOffset?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method on the server side that takes the current value of the date property and formats it into a javascript friendly string and return that from your mvc web api methods. Then you can create javascript date objects from this js friendly date string, because the js date object is cool like that.

For formatting questions see this answer:

[Javascript Date() constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work)