# date object return incorrect value

Tags: javascript, html, date

Hi I have use the following code snippet to convert the string to date object

```
var date = new Date("18/01/2011");
```

result of date as

```
Fri Jun 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2012
```

I expected the result of date as

```
   Tue Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2011
```

How to achieve this by using string provided in thee dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163563/javascript-date-constructor-doesnt-work/163584#163584

Answer (score 1):

The string `"18/01/2011"` is not in a form documented to be accepted by the `Date` constructor. In fact, until ES5, there *was* no documented form for that string. ES5 added a pseudo-ISO-8601 format. ("Pseudo" because, bizarrely, it handles an unspecified timezone *differently* from ISO-8601.)

In practice, though, all browsers support these formats:

```
yyyy/mm/dd
mm/dd/yyyy (U.S. format, even on -- say -- UK locale machines)
```

...though of course whenever using something undocumented, it's a risk, and you need to test carefully on your target engines. (In particular the `mm/dd/yyyy` seems surprising when implemented on non-U.S. locales.)

So one option is to reformat the string to fit one of those.

My preferred option is to parse the string myself and use the `Date(year, month, day)` constructor. Remember to subtract one from the month, as months start with 0. Your format is trivial to parse:

```
var parts = theString.split("/");
var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),     // year
                    parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // month
                    parseInt(parts[0], 10));    // day
```

Lastly: There are libraries to help with this stuff, such as MomentJS.

Answer (score 0):

The default format for JavaScript date is like: `month / day / year`

But if you don't have access to change the format you can do it like:

```
var datestr = "18/01/2011";
var dateArr =datestr.split("/");
var date = new Date(dateArr[1] + "/" + dateArr[0] + "/" + dateArr[2]);
```

The other overload of Date class constructor is simply pass the integers as its parameters, which its signature is like:

```
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

so the other and more reasonable approach would be:

```
var datestr = "18/01/2011";
var dateArr =datestr.split("/");
var date = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[2]), parseInt(dateArr[1]), parseInt(dateArr[0]));
```

you can also add `hour, minute, second, millisecond` to it if it was needed.

It is one of the best references, which has all you need to deal with dates in JavaScript:

[Global Objects: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Note that `month / day / year` is undocumented, not specified. I've never met an engine that didn't support it, but in theory, one could. In particular it seems very odd that engines in non-U.S. locales use the odd U.S. date format. Presumably for legacy support reasons.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks for your feedback, I tried to be more descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

the attributes inside the quotes are wrong:

new Date();

new Date(value);

new Date(dateString);

new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);

please checkout http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date or do a search on StackOverflow first