# Laravel - IE showing different time compare to firefox and chrome in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, laravel-5

I have an issue in my Laravel application.

The issue is that Internet Explorer is giving the wrong time compared to Firefox or Chrome in JavaScript.

My JavaScript Code:

```
console.log(expDate + ' --> ' + new Date(expDate).getTime() + " --> " + $.now());
```

It's output in Firefox:

```
09/25/18 4:31 PM UTC --> 1537893060000 --> 1537875054235
```

Output in IE:

```
09/25/18 4:31 PM UTC --> -1617866940000 --> 1537875062939
```

Can anyone help me with how to resolve the issue.

I want it so the `new Date(expDate).getTime()` gives the correct time in all browsers.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Solution**

My Issue was that `new Date(expDate).getTime()` was giving different timestamp in IE. So I solved my issue by to set date.

IE considers **09/25/18 4:31 PM UTC** this date to **09/25/1918**. 
Firefox considers **09/25/18 4:31 PM UTC** this date to **09/25/2018**.

So I just change the date format and picking exact date with exact years like 
**09/25/2018 4:31 PM UTC**. So I get same result as in firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)? What does `moment(expDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');` say? Otherwise, [maybe this thread can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837798/javascript-new-date-cross-browser-format-probleme).

Comment: No, I am using simple JavaScript. I just need the correct time but IE making issue.

Comment: Same Problem after trying your given thread.

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to try momentjs. You can get it running in a couple of minutes, so I guess it's worth a try. I use it in almost every project, and never had any trouble with cross browser Date stuff.

Comment: "09/25/18 4:31 PM UTC" is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. To get consistent results, parse using a bespoke function or a library, avoid the built-in parser. For the record, Safari returns `1537893060000`.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey Roosendaal to help me.